# How to set ATTRIBUTES in mysql to BINARY?

Tags: mysql

I was successful to create new column file with BLOB type, but now needed to set ATTRIBUTES to BINARY and having troubles with it. I tried ALTER TABLE listings MODIFY ATTRIBUTES BINARY; ALTER TABLE listings MODIFY file BINARY; did not work Thanx

Comment: Since you're changing the type, you would lose all the data in the column. I think the only way to do it would be to remove and re-add it `ALTER TABLE listings REMOVE COLUMN column; ALTER TABLE listings ADD COLUMN column BINARY;`

Comment: Why do you want to set the `BINARY` attribute on a a`BLOB`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `blob` field, `binary` is implied, it's basically the same as a `text` with the `binary` attribute. You can add the binary attribute to a `text` column, but not to a `blob`, it is simply not an available attribute (as it would be redundant).

See [The BLOB and TEXT Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html):

> BLOB values are treated as binary strings (byte strings). They have the binary character set and collation, and comparison and sorting are based on the numeric values of the bytes in column values. TEXT values are treated as nonbinary strings (character strings). They have a character set other than binary, and values are sorted and compared based on the collation of the character set.
>
> [...]
>
> If you use the BINARY attribute with a TEXT data type, the column is assigned the binary (_bin) collation of the column character set.